# AllJoyn - AJTCL - NVRAM Error

Tags: windows-10, alljoyn

I have a few errors when implementating the AJTCL on Windows10

After building the source with scons, when I try to run the basic_services or the basic_client samples i get the followiing errors

```
ERROR: AJ_LoadNVFromFile("ajtcl.nvram") failed aj_net.c:770
Mcast6up(): bind(): failed. WSAGetLastError()=0x271d
```

Is there something I am missing to include?

PS: I manually started the Alljoyn Router present in the Windows10

Also,

```
ERROR: AJ_LoadNVFromFile("ajtcl.nvram")failed
```

occurs only the first the time the program is executed and it creates a new file *ajtcl.nvram*.

Comment: the error message should probably be a warning. as you noticed, it creates the file for you. I don't think IPv6 is supported for TCL. Do the samples work?

Comment: @RyJones Yes the samples are working fine. Thank you for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: I copied to an answer below. could you accept that answer to close the question? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message should be a warning. [I filed a bug.](https://jira.allseenalliance.org/browse/ASACORE-2724)

IPv6 is not supported yet for AJTCL.

Comment: I require another clarification regarding the same `ERROR: AJ_LoadNVFromFile("ajtcl.nvram")failed` when implementing on a Raspberry Pi(Raspian). Unlike in Windows the Raspberry Pi doesnot create the `ajtcl.nvram`file and hence it produces an `_AJ_StoreNVToFile()=AJ_ERR_FAILURE` error, but the program executes successfully.